# Most efficient way of sampling a product of distributions $k \cdot f(x) \cdot g(x)$, given that PDFs $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can easily sampled?

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo

Is there an efficient approach tailored to sampling from a PDF $k \cdot f(x) \cdot g(x)$ (where $k$ is a normalizing constant) that would perform better than naive Metropolis, slice sampling, etc.? Can we exploit the fact that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can already easily be sampled from?

An example of this might be sampling $X \sim k \cdot f(x|a) \cdot f(e^x|b)$ where $f(x|\theta)$ is the normal distribution, and $a$ and $b$ are known. Note that the terms aren't independent, so Gibbs sampling wouldn't necessarily help (this is actually meant to be part of a Gibbs sampler).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are other methods based on rejection sampling

> Marrelec, G. and Benali, H. (2004). Automated rejection sampling from product of distributions. *Statistics and Computing* Volume 19, Issue 2, pp 301-315.

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02892062

The authors claim that this method is efficient.

> From there, we show that an automated selection of both the comparison
>   function and the upper bound is possible. Moreover, this choice is performed in
>   order to optimize the sampling efficiency among a range of potential solutions.

In my opinion, although this is a nice and ingenious method, if the $f$ and $g$ are not too complicated, then the use of MCMC algorithms might be easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I was hoping to avoid rejection algorithms, but this one seems like it might have a decent acceptance ratio if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are close. My implementation of a toy example (similar to that in the paper) was actually just four lines of Python code!

Comment: Is that code open source?? 